# Setting for hiding left navigation is ignored on logout page

Tags: bug, new-nav, navigation, preferences

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current

> [image: preferences page]

But on [logout page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/logout) this setting is ignored:

> [image: logout page]

Comment: There’s a few pages that hide it for everyone. It’s intentional. Not sure if this is one of them.

Comment: @Catija so...[tag:status-bydesign]? (: